# Импорт содержимого бинарного файла в json

Tags: python, binary-file

Этот код позволяет импортировать данные из одного бинарного файла в файл json.
В бинарном файле есть информация, которая поделена на блоки и подблоки, мне необходимо вытащить эти блоки в файл json, но возникла проблема с одним подблоком, у которого часто меняется длина символов.

1 блок из бинарника:

```
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
```

Первые 4 байта - количество символов всего файла.
Далее 4 байта - ff ff ff ff (просто пропускаем)
Далее 4 байта - это первый подблок,это то, что записывается в club['id'], там 4 значений идентификатор.
Далее 4 байта - это длина символов предстоящей строки с названием клуба.
После этого собственно и идёт название клуба, а затем снова 4 байта предстоящего названия, и таких названий будет 4.
Далее идёт идентификатор страны из двух символов, а после следом идёт идентификатор второй страны.

И вот затем идёт подблок, который нужно просто выписать в club['unk'] как идентификатор, но проблема в том, что длина этого подблока меняется нелогическим образом. Сначала эта длина составляет 327 байтов, но после около 50 подблоков длина будет составлять 397,и так далее. Можно конечно через if elif прописывать разную длину подблока, зная где он будет меняться и как. Я сначала так и пытался сделать, но спустя 20 вариаций понял, что это не вариант, поскольку в бинарном файле всего около 70 000 блоков, и как минимум 5 тыс этот подблок будет менять свою длину.

После этого меняющегося свой размер подблока всё идёт по кругу - club['id'] , потом названия name1 и так далее.

Задача: длина подблока club['unk'] часто меняется, как можно предусмотреть это в скрипте?

Желательно сразу с кодом.

Также есть файл json, в котором есть полный список name1, name2, name3 и name4, если делать по им поиск, можно понять конечную позицию "unk"? Как это реализовать?

```
import json

def readInt(file, size=4):
    """Returns a 32 bit integer from the file"""
    return int.from_bytes(file.read(size), "little")

def readStr(file):
    """Returns a string from the file"""
    size = readInt(file)
    return file.read(size).decode("UTF-8")

with open("club.dat", 'rb') as datFile:
    datFile.read(8)
    clubs = []
    size = readInt(datFile)
    trace = True
    for i in range(size):
        print("#", i + 1, "/", size)
        club = {}
        datFile.read(4)
        club['id'] = readInt(datFile, 4)
        club['name1'] = readStr(datFile)
        datFile.read(1)
        club['name2'] = readStr(datFile)
        datFile.read(1)
        club['name3'] = readStr(datFile)
        club['name4'] = readStr(datFile)
        club['nation1'] = readInt(datFile, 2)
        club['nation2'] = readInt(datFile, 2)
        club['unk'] = readInt(datFile, 327)
        clubs.append(club)

with open("clubs.json", 'wt') as jsonFile:
    json.dump(clubs, jsonFile, ensure_ascii=False, indent=2)
```

Результат первого блока:

````
"id": 4294967291,
    "name1": "Algeria",
    "name2": "Algeria",
    "name3": "ALG",
    "name4": "ALG",
    "nation1": 0,
    "nation2": 0,
    "unk": тут 327 символов этого подблока
```
````

Comment: Если вообще нет никакой привязки (ни фиксированной длины блока, ни выравнивания внутри файла) - то тупо идти по одному байту, пока эта серия ff не кончится.

Comment: Вроде как есть только одно, что связывает этот меняющий подблок, конец у них всегда такой: ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff00

Comment: Начало, середина, длина подблока меняется...

Comment: Ну вот находите этот конец, по нему считайте сколько там байт в unk

Comment: Кстати, 4294967291 на самом деле не 4294967291, а -5, если декодировать как знаковое число: `int.from_bytes(file.read(size), "little", signed=True)`

Comment: @insolor спасибо. Подскажите примером как можно реализовать по поиску конца подблока?

Comment: Можно тупо циклом, считать количество идущих подряд ff, останавливаться при нахождении 00.

Comment: Сделал так: start_pos = datFile.tell()
        end_pos = datFile.read().find(b'ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff00')
        if end_pos == -1:
            end_pos = datFile.tell()
        else:
            end_pos += start_pos
        club['unk'] = readInt(datFile, end_pos - start_pos)

Comment: Но теперь после "unk" в json пусто: {
    "id": 4294967291,
    "name1": "Algeria",
    "name2": "Algeria",
    "name3": "ALG",
    "name4": "ALG",
    "nation1": 0,
    "nation2": 0,
    "unk": 0
  },
  {
    "id": 0,
    "name1": "",
    "name2": "",
    "name3": "",
    "name4": "",
    "nation1": 0,
    "nation2": 0,
    "unk": 0

Comment: Ну у вас действительно буквы f в файле, или это байты `\xff`? Я предполагаю, что второе, тогда нужно импортировать binascii, и превращать буквы в байты так `.find(binascii.unhexlify(b'ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff00'))`

Comment: Не изменилось ) также пустой файл выходит, после первой unk и далее пусто

Comment: Также есть файл json, в котором есть полный список name1, name2, name3 и name4, если делать по поиск по этим названиям, можно найти конечную позицию "unk"? Как это реализовать?